# Why pixels color are different before and after encoding? , How to set the same?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I want to change some pixels of some frames, I do this steps:

1 - Extract frames from FLV video to PNG

2 - Change frame pixels color ,For example I set color of Pixel(0,0) to ARGB (0,0,0,0)

3 - Encode frames to a video by below code:

```
-i Frame%04d.png -filter_complex "[0:0] scale= [wm]; [wm][1:0] overlay=1:1 [out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a  -c:v libx264 -vprofile low outfile.flv
```

But when I check "outfile.flv" frames , pixel 0,0 is 255,7,2,3 instead of 0,0,0,0 , why? Please tell me that how can I get same pixels color after encode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video compression is a lossy process. To make the files smaller, an encoder will find areas of the image where it believes complexity can be removed without a difference that is perceivable by the human eye. You can use a lossless compression (by setting the quantizer to 0), but you would need to confirm that encoder is not performing a color space conversion as they are not perfectly reversible in most cases. And if you do uses a lossless compression, and color conversion, your final file size will be very large.

Comment: If you can stay in rgb land you might get "better" losslessness, I suppose

Comment: @rogerdpack true assuming sRGB and no secondary gamma correction. Otherwise a conversion may still take place.